Product Creation in License 4J Manager Succeeds But Doesn't Display
Stack Overflow community!
I'm currently working with License 4J Manager and I'm facing an issue when creating a product. The product creation process completes successfully without errors, but the newly created product doesn't display on the UI.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:
Successfully creating the product without any issues.
Checking for any errors in the console or logs, but nothing appears.
Trying to refresh the UI or restart the application, but the product still doesn't show.
Could anyone provide insight into why this might be happening or suggest any debugging steps I can take? I’d appreciate any help!
I'm currently working with License 4J Manager and I'm facing an issue when creating a product. The product creation process completes successfully without errors, but the newly created product doesn't display on the UI.
